# How to disable file upload dialog with selenium python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm trying to drag&drop a image to:

```
<input class="aaa" multiple="" name="bbb" style="display:none;" type="file">
```

with:

```
path=os.getcwd()+r'\\'
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.aaa"))).send_keys(path+"b.png")
```

I can drag and drop the image with this way, but, file upload dialog is shown (I don't need it to be shown).

How to disable (or ignore) the file upload dialog? I don't need it to be shown.

:ps

screenshot of the element: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pasVs.png

whole code: https://pastebin.com/xbQWViRh

took a video: http://fast-uploader.com/file/7066754812461/